# WooCommerce - Call to undefined function is_woocommerce()

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, 500-internal-error

new here and to wordpress plugins development, go easy on me :D

Anyway, I am trying to create a new plugin and I am getting a 500 error.
I changed `WP_DEBUG` in config.php to true in order to see what is causing the 500 error and got this message:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_woocommerce() in...`

This is my code currently:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: 
 * Plugin URI: 
 * Description: 
 * Author: 
 * Author URI: 
 * Version: 1.0
 * Text Domain: 
 *
 * Copyright: (c) 2018
 *
 * License: 
 * License URI: 
 *
 * @author    
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2018
 * @license   
 *
 */
//
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or exit;
if (function_exists(is_woocommerce())) {
    echo "test: ".is_woocommerce();
} else {
    echo "test: Function does not exists!";
}
```

If you need any more information, tell me and I'll edit the question.
Help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you don't use `function_exists` correctly https://secure.php.net/function_exists

Comment: Fixed the use of `function_exists` but I am getting false on
`if (function_exists('is_woocommerce'))`

Comment: WooCommerce won’t be loaded when you use the function naked like that. Make sure you’re only using that function in a template or a hook that occurs after all plugins are loaded.

Comment: So if I want to create a plugin which relies on WooCommerce, how can I achieve it? for example if I want the plugin to do something only on product-category page?

Comment: if you want to be sure that woocommerce is active you can use 
 if class_exists('woocommerce'){
// do something
} 
OR

is_multisite() ? $filter=get_blog_option(get_current_blog_id(), 'active_plugins' ) : $filter=get_option('active_plugins' );
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', $filter) ) ) {
//do something if woocommerce is active
}
if you want to do something in a template it's safe to overwrite the templates: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: I changed my PHP version from 8.0 to 7.4, then problem was solved

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check one Plugin's Function / Class etc. from another Plugin, then it's best to use a hook like [`plugins_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded).

Based on this, your Plugin CODE will look like:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: YOUR PLUGIN NAME
*/

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or exit;

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'plugin_prefix_woocommerce_check' );
    function plugin_prefix_woocommerce_check() {
    if( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) ) { 
        add_action( "wp_footer", "wpse_woocommerce_exists" );
    }   
    else {
        add_action( "wp_footer", "wpse_woocommerce_doesnt_exist" );
    }   
}   

function wpse_woocommerce_exists() {
    echo "<h1>WooCommerce Exists!</h1>";
}   

function wpse_woocommerce_doesnt_exist() {
    echo "<h1>WooCommerce Doesn't Exists!</h1>";
}
```

Directly checking other plugin functions will often lead to error, since WordPress may not be done loading other plugins by the time your CODE executes. However, when WordPress is done, it'll fire the `plugins_loaded` hook.

Check [Plugin Development Guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) for more information on how to develop a WordPress Plugin.

Comment: I am using the code you've provided but nothing happens, I tried looking for the word "test" in the page source but there is none.

Comment: Did you activate the plugin from WordPress admin panel?

Comment: Updated the CODE so that the test TEXT appears in the footer. Doing `echo` on `plugins_loaded` hook will print the text CODE  before HTML starts generating. So that's not a good idea. The original CODE was posted just as a concept of using `plugins_loaded` hook. There are better ways to debug WordPress. Obviously echoing text is not a good debugging method.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be a relevant answer.

However, I was receiving a very similar error after updating the Divi theme.

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function et_is_woocommerce_plugin_active()
```

I deleted the old Divi directory in the theme directory and replaced with the new Divi directory.

I tend to also delete the directory `/wp-content/et-cache` as well, when updating Divi.

Anyways, long story short, I ran this WP CLI command after updating the Divi theme.

```
wp transient delete --all --skip-packages --skip-themes --skip-plugins
```

The error was immediately resolved, and the updated Divi theme was functioning as expected once again.